# Laravel - sync with extra column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables

**type**

```
type_id
```

**person**

```
person_id
```

**category**

```
category_id
table_name
table_id
person_id
```

In category I have connections of different tables/models with Type model, So if I have want to get type_id connected with person with person_id = 23 the query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE table_name='person' AND table_id = 23
```

In my **Person** model I defined relationship with Type this way:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Type', 'category',
        'table_id', 'type_id')->wherePivot( 'table_name', '=', 'person' );
}
```

When I want to get those types and I use:

```
$person->groups()->get()
```

The query looks like this:

```
select `type`.*, `category`.`table_id` as `pivot_table_id`, `category`.`type_id` as `pivot_type_id` from `type` inner join `category` on `type`.`type_id` = `category`.`type_id` where `category`.`table_id` = '23' and `category`.`table_name` = 'person';
```

so it seems to be correct.

But I would like to use `sync()` for synchronizing types with persons and here's the problem.

When I use:

```
$person->groups()->sync('1' => ['table_name' => 'person']);
```

I see the query that gets all records from category to use for `sync` looks like this:

```
select `type_id` from `category` where `table_id` = '23';
```

so it doesn't use

```
`category`.`table_name` = 'person'
```

condition so synchronization won't work as expected.

Is there any simple way to solve it or should I synchronize it manually?

Comment: I just made a quick test reproducing the models as you posted them and this `Person::find(1)->groups()->sync(['1' => ['table_name' => 'person']])` generates this `SELECT type_id FROM category WHERE table_name = "person" AND table_id = 1`. So it seems to work just as it should be expected.

Comment: @Bogdan Are you sure for that? I've just used `Person::find(1)->groups()->sync(['1' => ['table_name' => 'person']]);` and I'm getting `select `type_id` from `category` where `table_id` = '1';` What version of Laravel ? Maybe it's a bug in Eloquent in L5 (I'm not using current commit yet)?

Comment: It may be a problem in L5. I've only done the test in 4.2.

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you for checking. I've tested it today in L5 final and now it's working fine. It was probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Eloquents polymorphic relations (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function categorizable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}

class Person extends Eloquent {

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Category', 'categorizable');
    }

}
```

Now we can retrieve catgories from person:

```
$person = Person::find(1);

foreach ($person->categories as $category)
{
    //
}
```

and access person or other owner from category:

```
$category = Category::find(1);

$categorizable_model = $category->categorizable; //e.g. Person
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it was a bug in Laravel 5 commit I used. I've upgraded for Laravel 5 final version and now query is generated as it should.